# "Последовательно прожить жизнь" сочетабельное сочетание?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> Говорят, умереть за идею легко, гораздо сложнее последовательно
>   прожить жизнь во имя неё.

Возможно ль проживать жизнь непоследовательно?

И: здесь неё/её синонимичны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Последовательно прожить жизнь" воспринимается столь же странно, как "прожить жизнь по плану", в то время как признанные мудрецы определяют её противоположным образом: "это то, что с вами происходит, пока вы строите совсем другие планы (на жизнь)". Автор, видимо, имел в виду "всю жизнь *последовательно придерживаться* этой идеи (или стремиться к её осуществлению)".